# Ubuntu 20.04 screen flicking and glithing

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, amd

I've installed ubuntu 20.04 in my computer, and I'm having troubles with some flitchig and flicking.
My specs are those:
Amd Ryzen 3 3200G With Vega 8 GPU
16GB of RAM DDR4 3200MHz
Mother Board Gigabyte B450 DS3H
SSD Samsung EVO860
I've been trying some config in grunt but didn't worked, this are the solutions I've been trying up:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239149/graphics-glitches-and-artifacts-with-ryzen-5-3400g-apu

https://www.muylinux.com/2020/07/30/forzar-driver-amdgpu-vieja-grafica-amd/

The last thing I've done is log in in "ubuntu on wayland" and the flicks and glitchs reduced a lot, but it still happening sometimes

This is what was happeing
[image]

After "ubuntu on wayland" it's working better, but still glitching sometimes:

[image]

I though that maybe the problem was the OS, so I've tried to install Debian, but when I was chosing graphical installation, this was happening (tried 3 times, and allways the same)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgrnu.jpg

So I think that maybe the vega 8 isn't at all compatible with ubuntu, but This computer MUST be used on linux.

[EDIT]

Maybe if I try another desktop environment that is not GNOME it could work better?

Comment: This probably doesn't help that much, but I can assure you that Vega 8 is supported under Ubuntu and causes no glitches to me whatsoever. What might be causing an issue for you is a RDRAND() Bug in your CPU (which is prominent in the 3000 cpu series), which always returns 0xFFFFFF or similar.

Comment: And so what should I do ? @SirMuffington

Comment: You can test whether you have the bug using this software: https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/rdrand-test.zip If you have the bug you need to update your microcode

Comment: @SirMuffington I've runned the tool but it says that I don't have the amd bug. `Your RDRAND() does not have the AMD bug.`

Comment: And it runs without problems on Windows with Windows Drivers? Just to make sure that it isn't a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you try the firmware-solution from the askubuntu-post? Is your BIOS up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I solved it placing an old nvidia GPU